# How to download Google Maps satellite images and save coordinates information related to the image?

Tags: java, javascript, api, google-maps

I have Google Maps related problem, and can't find the way how implement it. Try to imagine program that do next:

- download Google Maps satellite view image (in some specified zoom level) for some area. For instance we want image for all England.
- this "England photo" will be split in some number of tiles and packed into the archive
- in the archive we need to save (in separate XML file) information about coordinates on this images

Why we need this? After, in other part of the program, we can do next:

- user asks as: "Show me please map for the point 51°30′26″/0°07′39″
- and we can display part of the "England photo" with London in the centre.

This is something like offline version of Goole Maps.
Does someone know how it can be done (JS, Java, ...)?

Comment: The TOS will not allow this: http://www.google.de/intl/en/help/terms_maps.html

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically use the Google Static Maps API. I say theoretically because:

- it's impractical to save that much amount of data
- google will restrict the number of such downloads

Comment: That is the problem, that after studying the API I didn't found way to do this.

Comment: The API needs a point with coordinates or a textual "location" in order to return a tile to you. I guess it's up to you to come up with an algorithm of requesting tiles in such a way that you'd later be able to join them back into a larger map.

Answer (score 0):

http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@159000000&hl=en&x=297&y=192&z=9&s=Gal

in this url x, y ,z are very well known what they are.

but i don't think you can get this images for specific location because number are not related to each other with an easy pattern.

i think you need to make gmap.js file readable and then examine it for a long time